# Struct is non-literal type

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

```
struct rgb_color {
    constexpr rgb_color(std::uint8_t nr, std::uint8_t ng, std::uint8_t nb) :
        r(nr), g(ng), b(nb) { }

    std::uint8_t r; // red
    std::uint8_t g; // green
    std::uint8_t b; // blue

    constexpr static rgb_color black = rgb_color(0, 0, 0);
    constexpr static rgb_color white = rgb_color(255, 255, 255);
};
```

The `constexpr static` constant definitions fail to compile:

```
constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const rgb_color'
```

However according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType, `const rgb_color` should be a literal type, because it has only literal types as data members (`std::uint8_t`), and the `constexpr` constructor.

Why does the code not compile?

Also, is it necessary to define the `constexpr static` members in a `.cc` file, like

```
constexpr rgb_color rgb_color::black;
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `constexpr static rgb_color black(0, 0, 0);` ?

Comment: No: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7915407bb464659

Comment: The link you give has a suggestion: "possibly cv-qualified (C++17)". Your compiler may be playing by the C++14 rules here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This doesn't work, because you are instantiating a type that is not fully declared yet (you have not reached the closing brace and semicolon yet, so  `rgb_color` is still an incomplete type).

You can work around this by declaring your constants out of the class, maybe in their own namespace:

```
namespace rgb_color_constants {
    constexpr static rgb_color black = rgb_color(0, 0, 0);
    constexpr static rgb_color white = rgb_color(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to make `black` and `white` into `static constexpr` functions--i.e. this is an example of the "named-constructor idiom."

```
struct rgb_color {
    constexpr rgb_color(std::uint8_t nr, std::uint8_t ng, std::uint8_t nb) :
    r(nr), g(ng), b(nb) { }

    std::uint8_t r; // red
    std::uint8_t g; // green
    std::uint8_t b; // blue

    constexpr static rgb_color black() { return rgb_color(0, 0, 0); }
    constexpr static rgb_color white() { return rgb_color(255, 255, 255); }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not this?

```
struct rgb_color {
    constexpr rgb_color(std::uint8_t nr, std::uint8_t ng, std::uint8_t nb) :
        r(nr), g(ng), b(nb) { }

    std::uint8_t r; // red
    std::uint8_t g; // green
    std::uint8_t b; // blue

    static const rgb_color black;
    static const rgb_color white;
};

const rgb_color rgb_color::black {0, 0, 0};
const rgb_color rgb_color::white {255, 255, 255};
```

Comment: `const` is not `constexpr`

Comment: @chi True. What's the benefit of `constexpr` in this case?

Comment: That it won't work in expressions that require a constant expression. `constexpr auto dummy = rgb_color::black{}`, for example.

Comment: @black Yes, it won't work. But, maybe `constexpr` it is not need it (hence "Why not this?"). Now, that I see the accepted answer, I realize that it is a must.

Answer (score 2):

To update @zdf's answer, the following code works with C++17:

```cpp
struct rgb_color {
    constexpr rgb_color(std::uint8_t nr, std::uint8_t ng, std::uint8_t nb) :
        r(nr), g(ng), b(nb) { }

    std::uint8_t r; // red
    std::uint8_t g; // green
    std::uint8_t b; // blue

    static const rgb_color black;
    static const rgb_color white;
};

constexpr rgb_color rgb_color::black {0, 0, 0};
constexpr rgb_color rgb_color::white {255, 255, 255};

int main() {
    constexpr auto yes = rgb_color::black;
}
```

Link to the test case: https://godbolt.org/z/Q6FP_t